# TypeError: cannot convert dictionary update sequence element #0 to a sequence - Odoo v10 community

Tags: python, dictionary, odoo

I'm migrating some modules from v8 to v10, I have this model:

```
class SearchInfoPartnerSeniat(models.TransientModel):

_name = "search.info.partner.seniat"

vat = fields.Char(
    string='ID Number (Cedula, Passport, VAT Number)', size=64,
    help='The VAT number must be in this format J1234567890, if you'
         ' are looking for a cedula 12345678 and passport D123456789',
    required=True)
name = fields.Char(string='Partner', size=256, help='Partner name')
wh_iva_agent = fields.Boolean(
    string='Withholding Agent', help='It is withholding agent')
wh_iva_rate = fields.Float(
    string='Percent of withholding',
    help='What is the percentil of withholding that you must to apply'
         ' to this supplier if you are withholding agent')
vat_subjected = fields.Boolean(
    string='Pay VAY',
    help='Pay VAT, in spanish known as : Contribuyente formal')

@api.model
def search_partner_seniat(self):
    """ Check vat of the partner and update iva rate
    """
    self.ensure_one()
    vat = self.vat.upper()
    res = {
        'name': _('The requested contributor does not exist'),
        'vat_subjected': False,
        'vat': vat,
        'wh_iva_agent': False,
        'wh_iva_rate': 0.0
    }

    if 'VE' in vat:
        vat = vat[2:]

    # assumption: both methods in new api style
    if self.env['res.partner'].check_vat_ve(vat):  # check_vat_ve() should be @api.model
        res = self.env['seniat.url']._dom_giver(vat)  # _dom_giver() should be @api.model
    self.write(res)

    return {
        'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
        'res_model': 'search.info.partner.seniat',
        'view_mode': 'form',
        'view_type': 'form',
        'res_id': self.id,
        'views': [(False, 'form')],
        'target': 'new',
    }
```

And this is my view:

```
        <record model="ir.ui.view" id="view_vat_search">
        <field name="name">search.info.partner.seniat.form</field>
        <field name="model">search.info.partner.seniat</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <form string="Wizard to search partner on SENIAT" version="7.0">
                <group colspan="4">
                <field name="vat"/>
                <button name="search_partner_seniat" string="Search RIF" type="object" icon="fa-bars"/>
                </group>
                <separator string="VAT number consulted"/>
                <group colspan="4">
                <field name="name" readonly="True"/>
                <field name="wh_iva_agent" readonly="True"/>
                <field name="wh_iva_rate" readonly="True"/>
                <field name="vat_subjected" readonly="True"/>
                </group>
            </form>
        </field>
    </record>

    <record id="wizard_vat_search_action" model="ir.actions.act_window">
        <field name="name">Wizard Search VAT</field>
        <field name="res_model">search.info.partner.seniat</field>
        <field name="view_type">form</field>
        <field name="view_mode">form</field>
        <field name="view_id" ref="view_vat_search"/>
        <field name="target">new</field>
    </record>
```

Every time I click on `Search RIF` button it throws me this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/http.py", line 638, in _handle_exception
return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/http.py", line 675, in dispatch
result = self._call_function(**self.params)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/http.py", line 331, in _call_function
return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/service/model.py", line 119, in wrapper
return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/http.py", line 324, in checked_call
result = self.endpoint(*a, **kw)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/http.py", line 933, in __call__
return self.method(*args, **kw)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/http.py", line 504, in response_wrap
response = f(*args, **kw)
File "/home/kristian/odoov10/odoo-10.0rc1c-20161005/odoo/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 866, in call_button
action = self._call_kw(model, method, args, {})
File "/home/kristian/odoov10/odoo-10.0rc1c-20161005/odoo/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 854, in _call_kw
return call_kw(request.env[model], method, args, kwargs)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/api.py", line 679, in call_kw
return call_kw_model(method, model, args, kwargs)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/api.py", line 662, in call_kw_model
recs = self.with_context(context or {})
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/models.py", line 4850, in with_context
context = dict(args[0] if args else self._context, **kwargs)
TypeError: cannot convert dictionary update sequence element #0 to a sequence
```

I don't know what could be wrong here, is this about the dictionary return?

Any ideas?

The methods `_dom_giver` and `check_vat_ve` are as follows:

```
@api.multi
def _dom_giver(self, cr, uid, vat, context=None):
    """ Check and validates that the vat is a passport,
    id or rif, to send information to SENIAT and returns the
    partner info that provides.
    """
    if context is None:
        context = {}

    url_obj = self.browse(cr, uid, self.search(cr, uid, []))[0]
    url1 = url_obj.name + '%s'
    url2 = url_obj.url_seniat + '%s'
    vat = self._validate_rif(cr, uid, vat, context=None)
    if vat:
        return self._get_rif(cr, uid, vat, url1, url2, context=context)
    else:
        return False

@api.model
def check_vat_ve(self, vat, context=None):
    """ Check Venezuelan VAT number, locally called RIF.
    RIF: JXXXXXXXXX RIF VENEZOLAN
         IDENTIFICATION CARD: VXXXXXXXXX
         FOREIGN IDENTIFICATION CARD: EXXXXXXXXX
    """

    if context is None:
        context = {}
    if re.search(r'^[VJEGP][0-9]{9}$', vat):
        return True
    if re.search(r'^([VE][0-9]{1,8}|[D][0-9]{9})$', vat):
        return True
    return False
```

**EDIT**

Method `_validate_rif`

```
@api.multi
def _validate_rif(self, cr, uid, vat, context=None):
    '''validates if the VE VAT NUMBER is right
    @param vat: string: Vat number to Check
    returns vat when right otherwise returns False

    '''
    if not vat:
        return False

    if 'VE' in vat:
        vat = vat[2:]

    if re.search(r'^[VJEGP][0-9]{9}$', vat):
        valid_digit = self._get_valid_digit(cr, uid, vat, context=context)
        if valid_digit is None:
            return False
        if int(vat[9]) == valid_digit:
            return vat
        else:
            self._print_error(_('Vat Error !'), _('Invalid VAT!'))
    elif re.search(r'^([VE][0-9]{1,8})$', vat):
        vat = vat[0] + vat[1:].rjust(8, '0')
        valid_digit = self._get_valid_digit(cr, uid, vat, context=context)
        vat += str(valid_digit)
        return vat
    return False
```

And `_get_rif` method

```
    def _get_rif(self, cr, uid, vat, url1, url2, context=None):
    """ Partner information transforms XML to string and returns.
    """
    if context is None:
        context = {}

    xml_data = self._load_url(3, url1 % vat)
    if not self._eval_seniat_data(xml_data, vat, context=context):
        dom = parseString(xml_data)
        return self._parse_dom(cr, uid, dom, vat, url2, context=context)
```

Comment: Can you please share the methods `_validate_rif` and `_get_rif` ?

Comment: Done, Edited my question, Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buttons must use `@api.multi` + `self.ensure_one()`:

```
@api.multi
def search_partner_seniat(self):
    self.ensure_one()
    # do stuff
```

See [invoice example](https://github.com/OCA/OCB/blob/9.0/addons/account/models/account_invoice.py#L384).

Comment: No, they must not use `self.ensure_one()`. They could also handle more than one record, but should ofcourse work with one record, too.